# Find which row by y position

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, language-agnostic, computational-geometry

I am generating rows in canvas using the following:

```
var offset = 20;
var rowHeight= 17;

for (var row=1;row<20;row++)
{
     var yfrom = 4 + offset * row;
     ctx.strokeRect(0, yfrom, 300, rowHeight);
}
```

Now given a mouse position of say posY, what is the fastest and more efficient way to determine if the mouse is on a row or not, and which row?

I can easily brute-force it by searching on every row, but i know there is a better aproach but I cannot wrap my head around the maths for it.

Answer (score 3):

**Approach 1:**
You can maybe conduct a binary search on the upper y coordinates of rows. Once you get the location of the two rows between which your Y coordinate of mouse lies, you can check whether it lies inside the row rectangle.

**Approach 2:**
Or since you are calculating:

```
yfrom = 4 + offset * row;
```

You can back-calculate

```
(Y - 4)/offset;
```

Now say this number is `3.6`

Now check whether `Y` lies in row no. `3 or 4`.

Comment: This is a good approach, still is somehow brute-forcy if you know what I mean. I have the feeling there is a way to calculate it directly...if there is no such way then i will accept this as the answer

Comment: Thanks for that, it lead me to the answer. I will post it for future reference

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to Abhishek Bansal I got the answer i was looking for. So to calculate the row I use  Abhishek method:

```
var row = (Y - 4)/offset;
```

in order to know if I am inside the row or not I calculate the remainder of the division (modulus) and if it less or equal to row height then I am in the row, if bigger I am outside:

```
var inRow = (Y - 4)%offset <= rowHeight
```